# Possible paths of analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $U$ open. Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $f$ holomorphic. Let $p\in U$. Let $\gamma$ be path starting from $p$.

**definition** $f$ can be analytically continued along path $\gamma$ iff there exists an indexed finite set of tuples $(D_i,f_i)_{i\in I}$ where $D_i$ is a an open disc and $f_i$ is a holomorphic function on it such that for all $i,j \in I$ $f_i|_{D_i\cap D_j}=f_j|_{D_i\cap D_j}$ and for all $i\in I$ $f_i|_{D_i\cap U}=f$.

$V(f):=\{q\in \mathbb{C}: \ \exists $ a path $ \gamma $ starting at $p$ and ending at $q $ such that $f$ can be continued along it$\}$

The question is: can we perform analytic continuation along any path in $V$ starting from a point $p$?

So far, I have only encountered functions for which this is possible. For example: meromorphic functions, sections of functions as $z\rightarrow z^n$ and solutions of linear ode's on $\mathbb{C}$.

(edit: I want to stress that the resulting extension of $f$ could be multivalued, so that is not the issue.)

Comment: I think if the path crosses itself you will run into trouble, with e.g. $z\mapsto z^\frac12$ and a path that crosses itself after winding round the origin (or simply returns to its starting point). Then you will end up with different values of $f$ at the crossing point.

Comment: Hi TonyK, thanks, I am aware that an extension may result in a 'multivalued function'. But this is not the point.  The question is really if some other point is 'reachable' by analytic continuation along any path in $V$, without defining an extension on all points in $V$ or on the union of all discs in along the path.

Comment: If that is your question, then I don't understand it :-/

Comment: Consider the case of a local section of $z\mapsto z^2$. Then $V=\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$. We can perform analytic coninuation along any closed path through $V$ and the resulting local section we end up with is one coinciding with one of the two possible local sections. However, maybe there exists a function which can be continued once along a closed path, but not twice, or more.

Comment: I remember having seen an example of function that has a dense set of poles on the unit circle. Then it isn't possible to cross the unit circle.

Comment: md2perpe, I also know that example, but that does not awnser the question in any way. $V$ does not have to be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I see that I misunderstood the question, and now I do not understand the question. Your attempts to clarify unfortunately don't help. What do you mean with "continued once along a closed path, but not twice"?

Comment: md2perpe, I will clarify it what I mean with 'being able to continue a holomorphic function along a path' and write as edit my question in a moment.

Comment: My definition of analytic continuation is by the way precisely the one of S. Lang. You can find it in his book _Complex Analysis_.

Comment: The meaning of "continue a holomorphic function along a path" is not what I do not understand. What do you mean with "once /.../, but not twice"?

Comment: Oh, by concatenating the same path with itself, and continue along it the function would mean continuing twice along the path (in this context you need a closed path).

Comment: If you continue a function along a closed path you might end up on another branch at the starting point. Doing it a second time might result in a third branch.

Comment: Is the problem you see that some paths might not allow for a *finite* number of steps?

Comment: No, a path has compact image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a counterexample myself. Define $z\mapsto \log(z)$ as a local inverse around 1 of $z\mapsto e^z$ such that $\log (1)=0$. Define
$$
g(z)=\frac{1}{z-2 \pi i}.
$$
The set of points for which there exists a path starting at 1 along which we can analytically continue the function $g(\log(z))$ is $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$. However, we cannot analytically continue this along the path $t\mapsto e^{2t\pi i}$, since there $\log(z)$ reaches $2\pi i$ and $g$ explodes on that value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my copy of Lang's "Complex Analysis" handy to see exactly what he wrote, but I suspect that there is a small underlying misunderstanding that makes it harder to address this precisely.

Also, there is a not-so-trivial theorem (perhaps attributable to Weierstrass?) about a condition under which analytic continuation is guaranteed... Probably some version of it is in Lang's book. I believe also in Ahlfors'.

First, I have a suspicion that the desired hypothesis is something in the following direction: for some non-empty open subset $U$ of $\mathbb C$, for every $z_o\in U$ there is an open neighborhood $U_{z_o}\subset U$ of $z_o$ and a holomorphic function $f_{z_o}$ on $U_{z_o}$ (possibly a set of them, or a vector space, or...) ... with *some* sort of compatibility conditions on non-empty overlaps $U_{z_1}\cap U_{z_2}$.

(Typical instances are that the local bits $f_{z_o}$ are local solutions of an algebraic equation, or of a linear differential equation. But the set-up does admit some abstractions/generalizations.)

Then the theorem asserts the existence of an analytic continuation along any path inside $U$.

No, it does not assert that the analytically continued pointwise value(s) match the starting value, in case the path returns to the beginning point.

In fact, the Monodromy Theorem asserts that the values obtained by analytic continuation depend only on the homotopy class of a closed path (and base point, if the open $U$ is not connected).

Thus, analytic continuation (with a connected open) gives a group homomorphism from the first homotopy group to a Galois group, in the case of an algebraic equation, and to a group of automorphisms of the vector space of solutions to a homogeneous linear differential equation (with analytic coefficients...)

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: can we perform analytic continuation along any path in $V$ starting from a point $p$?

This question looks clear enough for me to answer it.

Yes, we can perform analytic continuation along any path having enough space around it to allow it. The resulting functions might however differ. These different functions are called *branches*.

Comment: This does not convince me. The possibility of analytic continuation along a path could also depend on its homotopy type.